# ActiveRecord Eager Loading after initial query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Let's say I have a simple model association, where a blog `Post` has many `Comments` on it.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_may :comments
end
```

If I wanted to avoid "N + 1" queries and eager load all the associations beforehand, I could do -

```
Post.includes(:comments).where(title: "foo")
```

Which runs two queries. The first one looks up the `Post` using the `where` condition and the second looks up all the associated `comments` at once.

But what if I already have a `Post` object? Can I "add" an `includes` to it after the initial result set to run the 2nd bulk query that looks up all the associations?

It seems counter intuitive to do a delayed eager load, but I assume looking up all the associations at once would still save me from having to look them up individually as I loop through them.

e.g.

```
p = Post.where(title: "foo")

# Will the below work?
p.includes(:comments)

p.comments.each do |comment|
  puts comment.text
end
```

Comment: Post.includes(:comments).where(title: "foo") this will actually run only query.
It should be something like 
select * from posts p inner join comments c on c.post_id=p.id where p.title='foo'

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down your code.

`posts = Post.where(title: 'foo')`

That searches for all posts with a title of `foo`.  `posts` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object and you can chain more `ActiveRecord` commands like `select`, `limit`, `includes`, etc.

So doing `posts.includes(:comments)` is valid and should eager load the comments.  Just don't forget to assign the result to `posts` again (or another variable).

What will not work is `posts.comments` because `comments` is a method that works on an instance of `Post`.  Changing to the following code will work

```
posts = Post.where(title: 'foo')
posts = posts.includes(:comments)

posts.each do |post|
  post.comments.each do |comment|
    puts comment.text
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense in terms of chaining multiple together